# Slow performance joining on ID with partitioned clustered columnstore table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

I have an Orders table that has a clustered columnstore and is partitioned on OrderDate (`datetime2(2)`). Has about 50 fields

It works great in most of our use cases. It's only when people need to join on the OrderID (natural key) that performance slows down and cpu spikes. This is an analytics table so this doesn't happen too often.
I don't think there's much that I can do since columnstores aren't meant for this kind of join behavior. But asking just in case.

I already have an index on `OrderID` for quick small lookups and it's quick. but joins with many records perform slowly. I tried a couple things (pseudocode below) but didn't help. I also tried including the partition column in the key (we could adjust some queries to join on this composite key if needed) but didn't help either.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx] ON tbl
(
    [orderid] ASC 
) on [DateMonthPartition]([orderdate]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx2] ON tbl
(
    orderdate asc, 
    [orderid] ASC 
) on [DateMonthPartition]([orderdate]
```

My guess is that this scenario isn't ideal for a nonclustered index and doing key lookups to the clustered columnstore.

Comment: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarling.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Comment: Please upload your execution plan(s) to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and link them in your post for us to be able to help you.